# Open File Filter not working

Tags: c#

I am making a program to open an Excel file in C# and get the data from it.

```
private void XLConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    type = 1;
    open.Filter = "Excel|.xlsx";
    open.ShowDialog();
}

public void readFile()
{
    if (type == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }
}
```

My problem with the code is that when the open dialog appears, it doesnt show any file to select. What is wrong in the code?

Comment: Just write `openfiledialog filter` to google. You will get many examples. -1 for no research effort.

Comment: @I4V I think that's nonsense, he's missing 1 character in his code (leaving the declaration of `open` out of it). He just missed that.

Comment: @Joetjah It is not a missing one-char problem. first link in search results shows many examples all using the `*`.

Comment: @I4V I know that, you know that, he missed it. We're not all perfect. For all you know he found the same site and saw that he had the same structure (`x|y|x`), and he wondered why it still went wrong.

Comment: sorry for the problems. Im a beginner in C# so i wasnt sure what to search for so i posted my question itself!!

Answer (score 2):

1. Use an asterisk in your filter.
2. Possibly your machine only contains the old style Excel-files?

Use this filter:

```
open.Filter = "Excel (*.xls, *.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx";
```

Comment: thanks. its working with an asterix.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a wildcard, in this case the asterix (*):

```
private void XLConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    type = 1;
    open.Filter = "Excel|*.xlsx";
    open.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: thanks!now that is working. but "Success" message isnt showing up!
for that what should i do?

Comment: @MärmîkŠhâh Is `readFile` being called?

Comment: @MärmîkŠhâh You show too little code to answer that. Do you call ReadFile? Where is `type` defined, etc.

Comment: no!forgotten that!
thanks, its solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared `open`?

```
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
```

As for the filter, use a `*`.

```
open.Filter = "Excel|*.xlsx";
```

Comment: ya i have declared open